# How to find icloud ID to activate my iphone

Tags: icloud, iphone

I don't know what I did but...
catch 22 I can't activate my iphone because I can't remember my icloud ID which I have stored in my iphone  I know my password but that does me no good???

Comment: Your iCloud ID is usually the same as your Apple ID.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean an Apple ID, right? There are one method that will be helpful to you.

- Find a Forgotten Apple ID by Email.

It is incredibly helpful if you switched email accounts at some point in time and that’s what has caused the login problem. This can be done with any web browser in iOS, OS X, or Windows:

1. Open the web browser of choice and go to this Apple [iForgot](https://iforgot.apple.com/appleid#!&section=appleid) page
2. Enter the first and last name associated with the Apple ID, your current email address, and any and all prior email addresses to start the reset process
3. Answer the security questions to complete the reset process